# I moved the /var to a partition to free space but don't know how to link it

Tags: partitioning, ssd, root, symbolic-link, 23.04

I recently setup Ubuntu 23.04 but it was setup wrongly so I ran out of space

it was supposed to be installed in both SSD and HDD but it only used the SSD one

so I started moving data manually so that the root doesn't fill up

I moved /var out and used the aid of this [solution](https://superuser.com/a/1041243)

I tried to do the same with /usr but the system crashed so I had to restore it to the root

now the issue is most of the apps I installed aren't there

all apps installed via the terminal except for Snap apps

Comment: Reinstall the OS, but this time, set it up correctly.

Comment: Simply moving `/var` is unwise. See the Filesystem Hierarcy Standard at `https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/fhs.shtml`, or read `man hier`.